# Add if-statement for a particular value to php array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I’ve got the following answer from a question I posted in WordPress Stack Exchange, but how do I add elseif (if-statement) for a particular value? For example, they might enter "£0", in which case I'll want to display nothing.

```
$giving_back = array();

$givingback_details_funds = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'givingback_details_funds', true );

if ( $givingback_details_funds ) {
$giving_back[] = $givingback_details_funds;
}

$givingback_details_days = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'givingback_details_days', true );

if ( $givingback_details_days ) {
$giving_back[] = _n( 'one working day', $givingback_details_days. ' working days', $givingback_details_days );
}

if ( ! empty( $giving_back ) ) {
echo 'the team donated' . implode( ' and ', $giving_back );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you may want to use either strpos or preg_match to search for the offending string:

```
if (strpos($givingback_details_funds, "£0") !== false){
    //do something where "£0" is in string
}
```

preg_match situation is for where space might be between the £ and 0.

```
if (preg_match("/^£\s*0$/". $givingback_details_funds)){
    //do something where "£0" is in string
}
```